# Is current related to the length of the conductor?

Tags: electricity

Ohm's Law tells us that $V = IR$. This implies that $I \propto \frac{1}{R}$. But, $R \propto l$, where l is the length of the conductor. This would mean that $I \propto \frac{1}{l}$. But this does not fit with the definition of current that says that current is the amount of charge $Q$ passing through a given point per unit time. Clearly, the amount of charge passing through a given point per second does not vary with the length of the conductor. How can this contradiction exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *fixed* voltage $V$, it is true that the current in a conductor having a fixed resistivity and cross-sectional area will decrease as the inverse of its length as you have indicated.  Thus, under these circumstances, the statement

> Clearly, the amount of charge passing through a given point per second does not vary with the length of the conductor.

is simply not true.  There is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The main form of the Ohm's Law (which is valid in some specific conditions) is actually the following:
$$\vec J=\sigma \vec E\tag{1}$$
where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the medium (usually an inherent property of the matter, so a constant in our calculations) and $\vec J$ and $\vec E$ are current density and electric field in the conductor, respectively. This form of the law holds *everywhere* and under all circumstances in the medium (*of coures, when the underlying physical law is valid*).

$\vec E$ and $\vec J$ are related to $V$ and $I$ through the following integrals:

$$V=-\int_a^b \vec E.d\vec l\tag{a line integral}$$
$$I=\int \vec J.d\vec S\tag{a surface integral}$$

The main and *real* physical quantities are $\vec E$ , $\vec J$ and $\sigma$ and the main law is $(1)$, but, using the above integrals, usually it is possible to obtain a constant of proportionality between $V$ and $I$ in a conductor,  i.e, ${V\over I}=C$ .The constant $C$ (or $R$) is called the resistance and is a function of the geometry of the arrangement and the conductivity $\sigma$ of the medium.

So, as is obvious from the above relations, when changing the dimensions of a conductor, the change in $V$ with the length of the conductor and in $I$ with the cross section area of it are indeed **the causes** of the change of $R$.

Since we usually deal with conductors with constant dimensions, we usually write this relation as $V=IR$ and use it to observe the changes in $V$ with $I$ (or vice versa) easier. But this form of the relation $(V=IR)$  may be somehow deceptive as it hides the main role of $V$ and $I$.

Comment: This was way over my head, but I could get the gist of it.